# How to clear or change the navigation history of Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a PhoneGap App using jQuery Mobile.
At a certain page, I cannot let the user go back to the last page he visited.

The pages order is like this:

```
(1)index -> (2)listing items -> (3)form submited -> (4)sucess page
```

**What I need:** I want to clear all history when the user is at `page 4` and set `page 1` as it were the last and only visited in case of the user tries to go back. Maybe that's not totally possible, then I would accept any suggestion.

I imagine jQuery Mobile stores navigation history in some kind of array, and I hope someone can help find that. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I'm using [multi-page template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html), which is a single html page, where certain divs works as pages managed by jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Basically you have two history "pots" you need to tamper with. Browser and JQM.

**JQM urlHistory**
You can modify JQMs urlHistory very easily. From the JQM code:

```
urlHistory = {
    // Array of pages that are visited during a single page load.
    // Each has a url and optional transition, title, and pageUrl
    // (which represents the file path, in cases where URL is obscured, such as dialogs)
    stack: [],
    // maintain an index number for the active page in the stack
    activeIndex: 0,
    // get active
    getActive: function () {
        return urlHistory.stack[urlHistory.activeIndex];
    },
    getPrev: function () {
        return urlHistory.stack[urlHistory.activeIndex - 1];
    },
    getNext: function () {
        return urlHistory.stack[urlHistory.activeIndex + 1];
    },
    // addNew is used whenever a new page is added
    addNew: function (url, transition, title, pageUrl, role) {
        // if there's forward history, wipe it
        if (urlHistory.getNext()) {
            urlHistory.clearForward();
        }
        urlHistory.stack.push({
            url: url,
            transition: transition,
            title: title,
            pageUrl: pageUrl,
            role: role
        });
        urlHistory.activeIndex = urlHistory.stack.length - 1;
    },
    //wipe urls ahead of active index
    clearForward: function () {
        urlHistory.stack = urlHistory.stack.slice(0, urlHistory.activeIndex + 1);
    }
};
```

So all of the above functions are available and can be called like this for example:

```
$.mobile.urlHistory.clearForward();
```

To monitor your history, put this somewhere and listen for pageChange (once transitions are done) to see what is inside the urlHistory:

```
$(document).on('pagechange', 'div:jqmData(role="page")', function(){
    console.log($.mobile.urlHistory.stack);
});
```

From there you can start to see what should be in the history and clean it up as you need.

I'm using this a lot for my own navigation layer to modify what is stored in the urlHistory and what should not be stored. Sync-ing with the browser is the difficult part...

**On sync-ing with the browser:**
In my navigation layer I'm only removing double entries from the urlHistory, so there is always a page to go to (and not two), when you click the browser back button. In your case, you will presumable have 4 entries in the browser history, but if you remove 2 entries from JQM urlHistory, you will have **two pages "not to got to"** when the back button is clicked. So if your browser history looks like this:

```
www.google.com
www.somePage.com
www.YOUR_APP.com = page1
    page2
    page3
    page4
```

And your remove *page2* and *page3*, clicking back-button should result in:

```
1st back-click = page4 > page1
2nd back-click = page1 > www.somePage.com [because you removed page3]
3rd back-click = www.somePage.com > www.google.com [because you removed page2]
```

A theoretical workaround would be:

1. keep a counter how "deep" you go into a page
2. remove pages from JQM urlHistory and get a "jump" value = counter-removedPages
3. on next browser back click, do jump x window.history(back) and only let one JQM transition pass. You url will unwind page4>page3>page2>page1 in one step and you only allow JQM to do a single transition from page4 to page1
4. check what's in the urlHistory and clean up after your "triple back"

Beware this is **not an optimal solution** and you have to consider a lot of things (user clicks somewhere else before going back etc). I tried forever to get something like this to work in a more complicated setup and eventually just stopped using it, because it never worked as it should. But for a simpler setup it may very well work.

Comment: May you be blessed by the old and new gods!

Comment: In JSF, for example, I've used this approach to override the jQuery Mobile's `data-rel="back"` button's click: `window.history.go(-#{managedBean.count});`, which would turn into `window.history.go(-3);`  if you are in the page 4, for example.

Comment: I do not find $.mobile.urlHistory in the jqm docs ... http://api.jquerymobile.com/?s=urlHistory

Comment: well. probably because one should not mess with it. Open a page using JQM and type `$.mobile.urlHistory` in the console

Comment: There is nothing that one should not mess with.

Comment: @jacobross85: once you know how to manage, you can do all kinds of magic like deeplinks, etc. So it's worth to mess with

Comment: This no longer works for jQuery Mobile >= 1.4.  See MOM's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Just an FYI;  in JQM **1.4** <strike>rc1</strike> there is no `urlHistory`, but you can read from navigate object.

example:

```
$.mobile.navigate.history.stack[0];
// Object {hash: "", url: "http://localhost:61659/"}

$.mobile.navigate.history.stack[1];
// Object {url: "http://localhost:61659/Search/Filter", hash: "#/Search/Filter", title: "Search Result", transition: "pop", pageUrl: "/Search/Filter"…}
```

and you can use this utility function to see whats going on:

```
$(document).on('pagechange',function() {
    console.log("Current:" + $.mobile.navigate.history.getActive().url);
    console.log("Stack: (active index = " + $.mobile.navigate.history.activeIndex + " -previous index: " + $.mobile.navigate.history.previousIndex + " )");
    $.each($.mobile.navigate.history.stack, function (index, val) {
        console.log(index + "-" + val.url);
    });
});
```

see also [here](http://blog.jquerymobile.com/2013/10/24/jquery-mobile-1-4-0-rc1-released/)

> Deprecated current behaviour of stripping query strings from hashes.
>   Starting in 1.5 we’ll be following spec on hashes and provide a hook
>   to handle custom navigation.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery Mobile uses the browser history for page to page navigation, so preventing the user from going back is not really possible in a browser. However, since you have a phonegap app, you can handle the back button directly. This question should help you: [Override Android Backbutton behavior only works on the first page with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631933/override-android-backbutton-behavior-only-works-on-the-first-page-with-phonegap)

Comment: I'm using multi-page template, using only one html file. I don't think it uses the browser history, but a ajax-like self managed browser history.

Comment: Yes, it's using history.pushState / changing the hash on browsers that don't support pushState. This still creates entries in the browser history which you cannot remove (not possible from javascript) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history .

Comment: It is possible to turn off this functionality from jQM, but that would mean you lose a big chunk of functionality with it, which you will have to implement yourself. The switch is ajaxEnabled: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple answer and so should be taken as such.  You may delete items out of the urlHistory.stack simply with

```
delete $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[index_of_your_choosing];
```

If you want to make sure the correct page is deleted you may do something like this.

```
var stack_count = $.mobile.urlHistory.stack.length;

for(x=0; x<stack_count; x++){

  $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[x];

  if(typeof $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[x] !== 'undefined'){

    if($.mobile.urlHistory.stack[x].url != 'http://url-to-exclude.com/'){

       delete $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[x];

    }}
}
```