# Handling back stack history

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a cordova application with jquery mobile using a multi html approach.

So I have an index page with basic html structure. All the other pages are just div's with data-role="page" that are loaded via [changePage](https://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/).

How can I delete pages from history? I tried to use splice() on window.history.stack, but it has weird behaviors.

Thanks.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884232/how-to-clear-or-change-the-navigation-history-of-jquery-mobile

Comment: it doesn't help. it's deprecated