# Over-ride the back button of android device through phonegap in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am making an app in HTML5 and javascript and deploying on android device. After confirmation  in the application, I don't want it to go back on previous page. But, on the back button of the device it goes on previous page.

I tried many demos. Following is one of the link I tried.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

I tried displaying alert for demo purpose. But it does not work.

Please help with your suggestions. Thanks.

I tried the following. It doesn't work. Do I need to add any external jquery file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        alert("On Load");
    }

     function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
        alert("Device Ready");
    }

    //document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false);

    function onBackKeyDown(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("back pressed");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you put event.preventDefault() in the method that is called when back button is pressed?

Comment: No I did not. I am trying now. If it does not work still, I will post the code of demo I tried.

Comment: Please find the edits in my question. It shows "on load" alert box, but not the other two alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to prevent the default behavior of back button is to add the prevent default method:

```js
document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(event) {
    // Handle the back button
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('I am a demo purpose alert thingy');
}
```

Comment: Are all the cordova/phonegap scripts included?

Comment: What if you try to put deviceready event registration outside of onLoad method?

Comment: I did it and also included cordova-2.2.0.js.But no effect.

Comment: Which device did you try it on?

Comment: Other alerts trigger properly? What if you try on an emulator?

Comment: It shows only the "On Load"alert. I tried on emulator also. It doesn't work.

Comment: So basically something is wrong with the registration of your deviceready event, as the code I provided MUST work. Did you try to put it outside of the onLoad function? Also maybe try to update cordova, maybe the 2.2 has a weird bug or something...

Comment: I tried in all ways. Currently, I followed he following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631933/override-android-backbutton-behavior-only-works-on-the-first-page-with-phonegap          I included cordova-1.5.0.js and downloaded a demo from https://gist.github.com/dhavaln/2020325 ,but even it did not work. I am stuck on the problem. Please can I get a working demo on it?

Comment: OK when I get home I will try to put something together.

Comment: It worked. You were right, instead of the cordova2.2 I used cordova.js and it worked. Thank You very much for your guidance. :)

Comment: You are welcome, so I my answer helped you I would politely ask to you mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the third parameter you pass. It indicates whether the listener uses capture or bubble. You find more information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

You want to capture the backbutton event at the beginning (capture) and not at the end (bubble).

So try this

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, true);
```

instead of

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: what android version is your phone running?
Edit: Also try putting alerts/console before the registration of the event and in the event method, to see if that code is passed.

Comment: Ok sry missed that you already have alerts. What I also highly recommend is remote debugging with chrome (needs android 4.0 or higher) see here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I use of the device back button with if else

```
//device back button functions
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    if($state.current.name == 'home'){
        // e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    } else {
       $state.go('home');
      e.preventDefault();

    }
}
```

Comment: What if he wanted to go back a state and not 'home' always?