# How to trigger event before Jquery (Phonegap )page is loaded, while going back using Android hard back button

Tags: jquery, events, cordova, single-page-application

I have a login Page as second page, first page is splash screen, third page is homepage, using the data-role=page in Jquery mobile

I have written code so that when user launches app and goes from first splash screen page to login page, if "remember login" was checked before, then login page is skipped.

However when the user logs in with remember login checked, doesnt exit app and uses Android hard back button, it comes to login page, I have no control of this.

So I need an event to be trigger while going back using Android hard back button, so instead of user going back to loginpage, it will skip to splash screen.

Does anyone know how to capture the Android hard back button, before page loads and skip page before it loads when needed.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9662760/1520425

Comment: @AhmedDaif Thanks, could you tell how to handle back button for only one JQuery page. If I handle for all pages, I have links that open Facebook pages inside the app, and the back button handle doesn't fire. I tried code like var mainPageRef = document.getElementById('mainPage');
        mainPageRef.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); but its not firing. If I give document.addEventListener.. it works well, but for all pages

Comment: I don't understand your problem well, but I always use `inappbrowser` plugin to handle external URLs,  don't know if this is your problem or not.