# How do I use the local copy of a PhoneGap plugin?

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am building an application with PhoneGap 5.2.2 in which the InAppBrowser plugin is used to display a website. When run on an Android device, I would like the Android back button to behave differently from how it normally does (it would normally close the InAppBrowser when tapped at the root of the embedded site), so I am following [this guide](http://rickluna.com/wp/2014/04/disable-android-back-button-in-inappbrowser/) to altering the InAppBrowser plugin's source code (a similar approach is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631933/override-android-backbutton-behavior-only-works-on-the-first-page-with-phonegap/9662760#9662760)) to prevent the default behavior associated with the Android back button.

I created the test application using the PhoneGap command line interface in Windows 7, and am using the PhoneGap Desktop software to "host" the application with the accompanying Android software to view it on my phone. Using the command line interface, I added the InAppBrowser plugin to my application and removed the  line from my config.xml file, then made the prescribed modifications to the Java file for Android in the plugin's source code.

However, I did not see any change take place within the application, even after further experimentation including rendering the Java file nonfunctional, and removal of the plugin entirely, which leads me to believe that the InAppBrowser plugin is being included some other way that takes precedence over the local copy. I have searched the codebase for any reference to InAppBrowser, and the only time it gets used is in the config.xml file (which as mentioned above, I removed the entry in). Even without the inclusion line in the config.xml file or any contents in the Plugins directory, the InAppBrowser appears to be behaving normally within the application (using the window.open(url,'_blank','location=no') method).

By default (in a freshly generated application from the CLI), where is the InAppBrowser plugin included, and how can I remove this or otherwise override it with my local copy containing my modifications? Once this is done, how can I ensure that this behavior carries over to the final application that is submitted for distribution?

Comment: cordova apps don't include inAppBrowser by default. Are you using the phonegap developer app on your phone and trying there? you have to compile and execute your own app to see the changes