# How to trigger cordova's backbutton event programatically

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a phonegap app based on jQuery mobile.
I'm trying to put a button in my app, behaving like back button on android  devices. I don't want just a `history.back()`, but I want the exactly same behavior, means going back when no handler is attached, and performing the handler when one is attached to the event `backbutton`.

**In other words, I want to simulate hardware back button, in software (exactly same behavior)**

I've tried these codes, with no success:

```
$("#backbtn").click(function(){
    var backButtonEvent = document.createEvent('Events');
    backButtonEvent.initEvent('backbutton', false, false);
    document.dispatchEvent(backButtonEvent);
});
```

What can I do?

Comment: check this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631933/override-android-backbutton-behavior-only-works-on-the-first-page-with-phonegap

Comment: @Banik This is not related to my problem

Comment: you have to programmatically trigger the native method... just posted an answer try this...

Answer (score 0):

import javascriptinterface package in mainActivity class

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
```

add JavaScript interface in onCreate method in the MainActivity Class

```
super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "sampleproj");
```

Then define the javascript Interface

```
public class JSInterface{
       @JavascriptInterface
       public void dispachBackKey() {
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
       }
}
```

Now call the native method in javascript

```
window.sampleproj.dispachBackKey();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, with some modifications. First, I had to import `android.view.KeyEvent` too. Second, I had to use `(WebView)appView.getEngine().getView()` instead of `super.appView`. At last, when I executed `sampleproj.dispachBackKey()` is JS, I got some errors: `Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation
    at Error (native) at <anonymous>:2:13
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)`

Answer (score -1):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    var backButtonElement = document.getElementById("backbtn");
    backButtonElement .addEventListener("click", buttonCallBack, false);
}

function buttonCallBack(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
}
function onBackButton(){
   // write your stuff
}
```

Try the above code it will work

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem

Comment: i am sorry i misunderstood your problem, i didn't study it clearly