# cordova backbutton event not firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to listen to the backbutton click on android devices as explained  [Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html). below is my code

```
var app = {
     initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
 bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', this.onDeviceResume, false);
    },
   onDeviceReady: function() {
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onBackKeyDown, false);
        app.receivedEvent('root');
        codePush.sync();
    },

onBackKeyDown: function (e) {
        if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
             navigator.notification.confirm(
                'You are the winner!',  // message
                onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
                'Game Over',            // title
                'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
            );
            e.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        } else {
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
    }

}

app.initialize();
```

My event don't seem to fire on backbutton click. I even added an exit to test yet nothing change.

```
onBackKeyDown: function (e) {
   navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Please how do i achieve that? Is there something i m doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

And my home.html below

```
<body>

<div id="root" class="root app">
    <div class="mobile-page">
        <img class="spinner" src="img/my-symbol-logo.svg" />
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

**Update**

content security policy.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: backbutton event doesnt support ios

Comment: @Rejs thanks for the prompt reply. But it doesn't seem to fire on android as well. Btw is there any alternative for the ios ?

Comment: You have to create custom button for back in ios

Comment: IOS devices does not have a hardware back button like Android devices. They have a home button. Besides that, at what point `app.initialize()` is executing, have you wrap it within any event ?

Comment: @Rejs any idea why it does not fire for android from in code above ?

Comment: @Rejs no i didnt. I just called the index.js file after my cordova.js . Please see my update above.

Comment: document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false); change device ready like this. It will register all listeners.

Comment: @Rejs tried , it does not seem to fire at all. :(

Comment: which version cordova using?

Comment: function onBackKeyDown(event) {
    // Handle the back button
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('alert');
}

Comment: @Rejs sadly it doesn't fire. I am running `cordova version 6.2.0`

Comment: I tried this, its works for me , It is the latest doc for 6.2 version .. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/de/latest/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html

Comment: @Rejs i am wondering could it have something to do with my content security policy which i added on the same home.html ? Please see my update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784742/override-android-backbutton-behavior-only-works-on-the-first-page-with-phonegap

Comment: If you remove content security meta is it working?

Comment: @Rejs thank you for your time. I really appreciate the help. "You have to create custom button for back in ios". Do you mean like add another button on the page ?

Comment: @Rejs, Shanmugapriya. I just release the problem after disabling the whole app. It's a hybrid app and It turns out the user is taking to an external links for authentication and after authentication regardless of the device. Cordova is not referenced on the external device hence the failure. It works when i disable the app.js and try to run within the local js. The app is quite big and a hybrid . Thank you guys. I would try referencing cordova on the external and see.