# jQuery Mobile : how exit an application on button click in native android application

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a HTML5+Jquery Mobile app, I converted the web view as Native android application using PhoneGap, I have written the following code to exit the application on Mobile. but this code not exiting the application. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**jQuery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#home", function (event) {
        $(document).on('click', '#exit', function (e) {
            if ( $('.ui-page-active').attr('id') == 'home') {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            } else {
                history.back();             
            }
        }, false);             

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data-theme="b" data-role="button" id="exit">Back</a>
        <h4> </h4>
        <a href="#page1" data-icon="forward" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip" data-theme="b">Next</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything with class ui-page-active and id home. Did you check if this condition was good ?

Comment: @Gaëtan "<div data-role="page" id="home"> and ".ui-page-active" currently active page class (jquery mobile class)

Comment: @Gaëtan such classes are dynamically added by jQM once page is rendered.

Comment: if you add a console.log or alert, do they fire? **edit:** if yes, they will fire once as you bound `click` event to `paginit`.

Comment: its firing in browser, let me check in AVD

Comment: @Omar I'm getting console message on AVD, "11-22 12:07:30.922: I/chromium(1677): [INFO:CONSOLE(14)] "test", source: file:///android_asset/www/Index.html (14)"

Comment: @Omar in console log, on page finished event happen its going to page 5 "11-22 12:19:50.952: D/Cordova(1884): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/Index.html#page5)
"

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602722/phonegap-android-back-button-close-app-with-back-button-on-homepage

Answer (score 1):

At last I found what I missed, I should add the `cordova.js` on my applications javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

Try change `$('.ui-page-active').attr('id') == 'home'` with `$.mobile.activePage.is('#home')`