# Android Back button exiting the app in PhoneGap+jQuery

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created an app with Jquery mobile 1.4.4 with PhoneGap.The app have multiple pages (each page in sparate html file).I am calling/navigating each page using

```
 $.mobile.changePage( "templates/login.html", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
```

When I am using back button in android to goback to previous page it exit the whole app.

I have followed the solutions mentioned here [Phonegap Android Back Button - close app with back button on homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602722/phonegap-android-back-button-close-app-with-back-button-on-homepage)

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
else {
    navigator.app.backHistory()
}
}, false);
```

The above solution is not working.How can i handle back page option in android PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
   e.preventDefault();
   navigator.app.exitApp();
   }
   else {
    history.back();
    return false;
   }
```

Comment: @Thamilvanan i have updated my answer,.add data-back="true" to the element if not working

Comment: I am not using button element for back option.am using default back  in android device.